# skipping Scanner input inside a do while loop in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have a problem with this homework. The program is supposed to run `registration()` first. If the user is below 13 years old, it will give an alert and should go back to `registration()`. If the user is more than 13 years old, it will run `displayProfile()` and ask for a confirmation, if the answer is yes, it will notify that it is a success and program ends. If the answer is no, it should go back to `registration()` and process repeats. If the answer is invalid, it should just keep on prompting for a valid reply.
The problem is in the `registration()`. At the start of the program, it works fine but when I enter a user that is below 13 years old and it goes back to the registration, it skips the input part for the last name and instead proceeds with printing out "First Name: ". It is in a do while loop because I want to validate if input is characters and white spaces only. For the other fields in the registration, everything is working. It is just on the prompt for the last name at the next run that it is not working. What is wrong with the algorithm?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class mainExercise{
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String lastName;
static String firstName;
static String email;
static String gender;
static String bday;
static int birthMonth;
static int birthDay;
static int birthYear;
static String confirmation;

static EmailValidator ev = new EmailValidator();
static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

public static void main(String[] args){

    do{

        do{
            registration();
        }while(validateAge(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear) != 1);

        displayProfile();

        do{
            confirmation = input.nextLine();
            }while(confirm(confirmation)== -1);

        if(confirm(confirmation)==0){
            break;
        }

    }while(confirm(confirmation)== 1);

    System.out.println("Thank you for registering, " + firstName);

}//end of main


static void registration(){

    System.out.println("Welcome to Old School Facebook");
    System.out.println("To register, please provide the following      information");               

    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    do{ 
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateName(lastName) != 1);

    System.out.print("First Name: ");
    do{
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateName(firstName) != 1);

    System.out.print("Email: ");
    do{
        email = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateEmail(email) != 1);

    System.out.print("Gender: ");
    do{
        gender = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateGender(gender) != 1);

    System.out.println("Enter birthdate");
    do{
        System.out.print("Month: ");
        birthMonth = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthMonth) != 1);

    do{
        System.out.print("Day: ");
        birthDay = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthDay) != 1);

    do{
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        birthYear = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthYear) != 1);


}

static int validateName(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    char name[] = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(name[i]) || Character.isWhitespace(name[i])){
            valid = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            valid = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateEmail(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    if(ev.validate(s)){
        valid = 1;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid email");
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateGender(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    if(s.toLowerCase().compareTo("m") == 0 || s.toLowerCase().compareTo("f") == 0){
        valid = 1;
    }else{
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateBirthInput(int x){
    int valid = 1;
    int birth;
    try{
        birth = x;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Enter numbers 1-12 for month, 1-31 for day, yyyy for year");
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateAge(int bm, int bd, int by){
    int valid = 1;
    int cm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int cy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if((cy-by)<=13){
        if(bm>=cm){
            if(bd>cd){
                valid = 0;
                System.out.println("You must be at least 13 years old");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }else{
        valid = 1;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int confirm(String s){
    int reply;
    if(s.toLowerCase().compareTo("yes") == 0){
        reply = 1;
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().compareTo("no") >0){
        reply = 0;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Type yes or no");
        reply = -1;
    }
    return reply;
}

static void displayProfile(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Email: " + email);
    System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
    System.out.printf("Birthday: %d/%d/%d\n\n", birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
    System.out.println("(yes or no): ");

}
}
```

Comment: I've added the homework tag for you. Please add this tag to questions related to homework.

Answer (score 2):

Heh, this one is pretty tricky.

Take a look at the javadocs for [Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int

Now compare that to what we have for [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So when you call `nextInt()`, you read only an "int" from the input, when you call `nextLine()` you read all the way up to the end of the line. Your Scanner is reading from `System.in`, which is a little peculiar in that it doesn't give any data to the Scanner until **you've hit <kbd>enter</kbd>**, putting whatever you typed into a line by itself. When you ask for a date/month/year, the user types in some number but nothing happens until the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd>, then you call `nextInt()`, it reads the number that's typed in.

So far so good, except that the Scanner only read the numbers that the user typed, and NOT the new line. So when you go through the `registration()` method again, there's a spare blank line in the Scanner, and the `lastName = input.nextLine();` instantly reads that, assumes it's valid, and then moves on asking for the first name.

Since this is your homework, take a look at what you are reading and what the user is typing in, keeping in mind that System.in doesn't hand anything off to the Scanner until the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd>. You could perhaps take a look at this [Integer method, parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) instead of using `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code. You can also change it according to yours.. 
Happy coding .. :)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainExercise{
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String lastName;
static String firstName;
static String email;
static String gender;
static String bday;
static int birthMonth;
static int birthDay;
static int birthYear;
static String confirmation;

//static EmailValidator ev = new EmailValidator();
static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

public static void main(String[] args){

    do{

        do{
            registration();
        }while(validateAge(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear) != 1);

        displayProfile();
// this is coming "Invalid input. Type yes or no"  because ist time input.nextLine() return ("") thats why.
        do{
            confirmation = input.nextLine();
            }while(confirm(confirmation)== -1 || confirmation.equals(""));

        if(confirm(confirmation)==1){
            break;
        }

    }while(confirm(confirmation)== 1);

    System.out.println("Thank you for registering, " + firstName);

}//end of main


static void registration(){

    System.out.println("Welcome to Old School Facebook");
    System.out.println("To register, please provide the following      information");               

    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    do{ 
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateName(lastName) != 1);

    System.out.print("First Name: ");
    do{
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateName(firstName) != 1);

    System.out.print("Email: ");
    do{
        email = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateEmail(email) != 1);

    System.out.print("Gender: ");
    do{
        gender = input.nextLine();
        }while(validateGender(gender) != 1);

    System.out.println("Enter birthdate");
    do{
        System.out.print("Month: ");
        birthMonth = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthMonth) != 1);

    do{
        System.out.print("Day: ");
        birthDay = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthDay) != 1);

    do{
        System.out.print("Year: ");
        birthYear = input.nextInt();
        }while(validateBirthInput(birthYear) != 1);


}

static int validateName(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    char name[] = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(name[i]) || Character.isWhitespace(name[i])){
            valid = 1;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            valid = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateEmail(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    // this is showing error. You have to first initialize ev variable  .
    if(ev.validate(s)){
        valid = 1;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid email");
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateGender(String s){
    int valid = 1;
    // you have to check whith 1st char of that string othrewise it always show false
    if(s.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1).compareTo("m") == 0 || s.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1).compareTo("f") == 0){
        valid = 1;
    }else{
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateBirthInput(int x){
    int valid = 1;
    int birth;
    try{
        birth = x;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Enter numbers 1-12 for month, 1-31 for day, yyyy for year");
        valid = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}

static int validateAge(int bm, int bd, int by){
    int valid = 1;
    int cm = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int cy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
// this should also need to change like following 
      if ((cy - by) > 13)
      {
         return valid;
      }
      else if ((cy - by) == 13)
      {
         if (bm>cm)
         {
            return valid; 
         }
         else if (bm==cm && bd>cd ) {
            return valid;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("You must be at least 13 years old");
      System.out.println();
      return 0;

}

static int confirm(String s){
    int reply;
    if(s.toLowerCase().compareTo("yes") == 0){
        reply = 1;
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().compareTo("no") >0){
        reply = 0;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Type yes or no");
        reply = -1;
    }
    return reply;
}

static void displayProfile(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
    System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Email: " + email);
    System.out.println("Gender: " + gender);
    System.out.printf("Birthday: %d/%d/%d\n\n", birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear);
    System.out.println("(yes or no): ");

}
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this helped. When I run this (at least it compiles now because `EmailValidator` is commented out) but I still see the same problem.

Comment: Yes I comment it because there is one variable "ev" that I don't know where it coming from so I put a comment that it him work to do it in right way..

Comment: @JonLin I tried to create two scanner objects, one for the String inputs using scanner.nextLine() and one for the integers (birthday fields) using scanner.nextInt() and it's working now. I guess the problem is on the functions that I am using rather than the algorithm in my do while loops

Comment: @SumitSingh thanks for the code although the problem was still there. It was fixed when I created two scanner objects. The validation of the birthday in the code you gave was not capturing those less than 13 years old like those born on 1999, the day after current date's month and day. Another problem is the code for validateGender() which goes for my code as well because when I type a single letter aside from m or f, i have to enter it twice before it takes the input and goes to the next line

Comment: @mike26 its good if its working now for you that s main think..